# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P (X + n = Y)$ where $X,Y$ are independent Poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> A pitcher contains $X + 1$ blue balls and $Y + 1$ red balls. It is known that $X, Y$ are independent random variables, and it is given that $X \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(n), Y \sim\mathrm{Poisson}(2n)$. Calculate the limit: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P (X + n = Y) $

I tried to condition on the value of $Y$ and to use the Law of total probability but it did not lead to a solution.
( I tried to sum: $ \sum_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb P(X+n=Y|Y=i)\mathbb P(Y=i) $ and get an expression that I can calculate its limit as n goes to infinity)

Comment: Can you estimate $\sup_k P(Y=k)$ as a function of $n$, by using Stirling's formula say?

Comment: No... the solution shouldn’t include Stirling’s formula

Comment: Does that mean you don't know how to prove it that way, or you are not allowed to prove it that way?

Comment: Not supposed to prove it that way.

Comment: Mathematica gave me
$$
\mathbb P(X+m=Y) = 2^{m/2} e^{-3 n} I_m\left(2 \sqrt{2} n\right),
$$
where $I_m$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. It wouldn't give me the limit as $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be independent random variables s.t. $V_i\sim \text{Poisson}(1)$ and $W_i\sim \text{Poisson}(2)$. Also let $X_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n V_i$ and $Y_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$. Then

$$
p_n:=\mathsf{P}(X_n+n=Y_n)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(n^{-1/2}(X_n-n)=n^{-1/2}(Y_n-2n)\right).
$$
Using the CLT,
$$
n^{-1/2}\begin{bmatrix}
X_n-n \\
Y_n-2n
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{d}N\!\left(0,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\right).
$$
Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}p_n&\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\!\left(n^{-1/2}|X_n-Y_n+n|<\epsilon\right) \\
&= 2\Phi(\epsilon;0,3)-1\le \sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}}\,\epsilon.
\end{align}