# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n+n = Y_n)$ If $X_n,Y_n$ have Poisson distribution of $Poi(n), Poi(2n)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

We are given a whole number $n \geq 1$ and independent Random variables $X_n$ with distribution $Poi(n)$ and $Y$ with distribution $Poi(2n)$. Determine $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n+n = Y_n)$.
 
 I tried to write the probability as$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X_n=k)P(Y_n=n+k)$ but I didn't make progress. I suspect I need to use one of the limits laws (Central limit, large numbers, small numbers) but I am not sure how. Suggestions?

Comment: @DanielSchepler This is how the question was given to me. I believe X,Y meant to be dependent on $n$. I'll edit that to $X_n, Y_n$.

Comment: Asked a few days back: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513701/find-lim-n-to-infty-mathbb-p-x-n-y-where-x-y-are-independent-poiss.

Comment: What happens to $(X_n - n) / \sqrt n$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Math1000 it does not.

Comment: @Omer Why? It is proved there that the limit is zero.